# Change the browser URL bar text

Tags: url, redirect, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I own a domain in a hosting provider (just the domain).  This domain is pointing to another web address:

`domain.com-->anotherdomain.dom/path`

In another side, I have added my domain to my Cloudflare account, like this:

`domain.com-->Cloudflare-->anotherdomain.dom/path`

The issue is that after typing `domain.dom`, the URL text in the browser URL bar is `anotherdomain.dom/path`, and I need it to be `domain.com`.

Is it possible to have `domain.com` in the broswer URL bar?  Do I have to write some code inside my `.htaccess` file or something inside `anotherdomain.com`?  Do I have to do something inside Cloudflare (maybe with "workers")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like currently, your domain `domain.com` is set up as a *redirect*. When a user visits `domain.com` in their browser, the server (Cloudflare) responds with a message saying: "Please go to `anotherdomain.com/path` instead." The browser then acts like the user actually typed `anotherdomain.com/path` in the address bar.

It sounds like what you want instead is for `domain.com` to be a *proxy*. When a request comes in for `domain.com`, you want Cloudflare to fetch the content from `anotherdomain.com/path` and then return that content in response to the original request.

In order to do this, you will need to use Workers. Cloudflare Workers allows you to write arbitrary JavaScript code to tell Cloudflare how to handle HTTP requests for your domain.

Here's a Worker script that implements the proxy behavior that you want:

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  // Parse the original request URL.
  let url = new URL(request.url);

  // Change domain name.
  url.host = "anotherdomain.org";
  // Add path prefix.
  url.pathname = "/path" + url.pathname;

  // Create a new request with the new URL, but
  // copying all other properties from the
  // original request.
  request = new Request(url, request);

  // Send the new request.
  let response = await fetch(request);

  // Use the response to fulfill the original
  // request.
  return response;
}
```